# Magnetic field of a plane wave hitting a conducting surface

Tags: electromagnetism, visible-light, waves, conductors, plane-wave

If the $E$ component of a plane monochromatic wave does not penetrate the conducting surface, what happens to the $B$ component? The $E$ field gets reflected back because we are talking about a conducting surface, but I'm not sure what happens to the magnetic field. Can they actually separate somehow? Or must the $B$ field necessarily follow the $E$ field wherever it goes?

Answer (score 0):

If it's a perfect conductor the magnetic field cannot enter the conductor. The boundary conditions for the wave fields are that the normal component of $B$ is zero and the components of $E$ in the surface are zero. If you do the math, this leads to a reflected EM wave. I can't think of a non-mathematical explanation, except to say that there are no purely electric or purely magnetic wave solutions to Maxwell's equations.